# Django 1.7 'list_filter' raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")

Tags: django, python-2.7

Django (1.7) raises AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.") whenever i tried to include `list_filter`.

```
class ChoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('choice_text', 'votes')


class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = choice.Choice
    extra = 4


@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['question_text']}
         )]
    search_fields = ['question_text']
    list_filter = ['pub_date']
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
```

Below i have included error traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\theindianpoll_repo_container\theindianpoll_dev_repo\theindianpoll\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 197, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\theindianpoll_repo_container\theindianpoll_dev_repo\theindianpoll\polls\models.py", line 19, in <module>
    class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\decorators.py", line 25, in _model_admin_wrapper
    admin_site.register(models, admin_class=admin_class)
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 99, in register
    admin_class.check(model)
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 153, in check
    return cls.checks_class().check(cls, model, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 497, in check
    errors.extend(self._check_list_filter(cls, model))
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 668, in _check_list_filter
    for index, item in enumerate(cls.list_filter)
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 713, in _check_list_filter_item
    get_fields_from_path(model, field)
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 457, in get_fields_from_path
    fields.append(parent._meta.get_field_by_name(piece)[0])
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 416, in get_field_by_name
    cache = self.init_name_map()
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 445, in init_name_map
    for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 563, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
    cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 577, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
    for klass in self.apps.get_models():
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 168, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\theindianpoll_virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Question Model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    """
    """
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

Choice model :

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    """
    """
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-votes']
```

If i remove list_filter everything worked fine.

Comment: Please add your Question model definition.

Comment: Can you double-check that the app containing the Question model (and other apps) are listed in INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: Yes it is... i already checked that. Rest is working fine.

Comment: Check to see if you're using ```admin.autodiscover()``` in more than one place.

Comment: I wonder if it's the fact that you have your admin classes defined in your models file. If you're still at a loss, you could try moving them into it's own admin.py file in the app.

Comment: No man i didn't used admin.autodiscover()...as far as i know it is enabled by default in Django 1.7...hope i am right

Comment: Strange it just worked. I just tried it again and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you registering the model in the models.py or in admin.py? List_filter requires the model to be loaded already so you have to register it in admin.py so models can load independently.